Не устанавливается модуль python
Пишу:
python -m pip install detextify

Выдаёт:
Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [24 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\MrKey8840\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
          ~~~~^^
        File "C:\Users\MrKey8840\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\MrKey8840\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "C:\Users\MrKey8840\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-5coajvd4\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 333, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=[])
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\MrKey8840\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-5coajvd4\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 303, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^
        File "C:\Users\MrKey8840\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-5coajvd4\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 521, in run_setup
          super().run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\MrKey8840\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-5coajvd4\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 319, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
          ~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "<string>", line 29, in <module>
        File "<string>", line 26, in get_version
      KeyError: '__version__'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

Ничего тут не понимаю, это можно как-то исправить?

Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Во-первых вы обрезали вывод и непонятно, что вы вообще ставите и какой командой.  Напишите это в вопросе. Во-вторых попробуйте сначала обновить setuptools У вас питон слишком свежий, с ним не всё совместимо ещё, а что-то и поменялось в экосистеме.

detextify на pypi с марта 2023 года не обновлялся: https://pypi.org/project/detextify/#history. Он скорее всего не только Python 3.13 не поддерживает, но и даже Python 3.12. Пробуйте setuptools установить отдельно или вообще откатиться до Python 3.11.

@insolor, спасибо помогло
